# How does one change the positioning of text based on screen size?

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

I want two pieces of text to be equal with each other horizontally until the screen gets too small, then the right text just slides under the left one so they become stacked vertically. Is it as easy as using the flexbox, or display?

A little bit like this:

```
 ________________________________
|text A <--------------> text B  |
|________________________________|
```

```
 _______
|text A|
|text B|
|______|
```

I am trying to accomplished this in just css.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)'s [`flex-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap) property:

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <h1>Text A</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h1>Text B</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```